# How to call two overloaded functions together if they have default parameters?

Tags: c++, overloading, default-arguments

I have two functions with same name and default parameters but when I call them both together it gives me error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add(int x=2,int y=4){
    
    cout<<x+y<<endl;
}

void add(int x=2, int y=14, int z=12)
{
    cout<<x+y+z<<endl;
}


int main(){
     
    add(5,9);
    add(2,3,6);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which of the functions should be called?

Comment: If you want `add(x,y)` to always call the first overload, why does the second overload need default arguments?

Comment: the same question has already been ask [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376620/function-overloading-with-default-parameter-in-c)

Comment: I certainly wouldn't expect the values to be non-zero. I'd expect the result to be the sum of all provided values. Maybe go with different functions for each variant though `template<typename ...Ts> void add(Ts...args) {std::cout<<(args + ... + 0) << '\n';}`, if you want to implement this.

Comment: What is the error? (It could help people with the same error find this question in the future.)

Comment: If you tried calling `add()` (with no arguments, since each has a default), which function do you expect will be called?

Comment: This are the errors
E:\Programs\Day 11.cpp [Error] call of overloaded 'add(int, int)' is ambiguous
E:\Programs\Day 11.cpp [Note] candidates are:
E:\Programs\Day 11.cpp [Note] void add(int, int)
E:\Programs\Day 11.cpp [Note] void add(int, int, int)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot distinguish which function should be called, because they both equally match. You can help the compiler by explicitly selecting one overload via `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<void(*)(int,int)>(add)(5,9);        // calls void add(int x=2,int y=4)
static_cast<void(*)(int,int,int)>(add)(2,3,6);  // calls void add(int x=2, int y=14, int z=12)
```

However, this defeats the purpose of providing overloads (same name but different function). Hence you should change the defaults such that the calls are not ambiguous. For example remove them altogether:

```
void add(int x,int y){
    
    cout<<x+y<<endl;
}

void add(int x, int y, int z)
{
    cout<<x+y+z<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there should be defaults for the 2 parameter version, since lacking the default parameters of the 3 param version there's never an ambiguity: 3 params would result in the second function being called, less than 3 and the first function would be used. This would retain the possibility of calling `add` with less than 2 params specified.

Comment: @fabian maybe. OP didnt explain why there are defaults in the first place. I try to avoid them when possible. Actually I would consider to write 5 different overloads when the function should be called with 4,3,2,1 or 0 parameters

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that `add(5,9);` is ambiguous, because the compiler can't determine if you want to call the first overload with `x` and `y` specified or the second overload with `x` and `y` specified and `z`  defaulted to `12`.